# SCDF: Restart and resume a composed task

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

SCDF Composed Task Runner gives us the option to turn on the *--increment-instance-enabled*.  This option creates an artificial *run.id* parameter, which increments for every run. Therefore the task is unique for Spring Batch and will restart.

The problem with the IdIncrementer is when I mix it with execution without the IdIncrementer. In the event when a task does not finish, I want to resume the Task. The problem I encountered was when the task finishes without the IdIncrementer, I could not start the task again with the IdIncrementer.

I was wondering what would be the best way to restart with the option to resume?

My idea would be to create a new IdResumer, which uses the same *run.id* as the last execution.

We are run SCDF 2.2.1 on Openshift v3.11.98 and we use CTR 2.1.1.

The steps to reproduce this:

1. Create a new SCDF Task Definition with the following definition: `dummy1:dummy && dummy2: dummy  && dummy3: dummy`. The dummy app is a docker container, that fails randomly with 50% chance.
2. Execute the SCDF Task with the `--increment-instance-enabled=true` and wait for one of the dummy task to fail (restart if needed).
3. To resume the same failed execution, execute the SCDF Task now `--increment-instance-enabled=false`. And let it finish successfully (Redo if needed).
4. Start the SCDF Task again with `--increment-instance-enabled=true`.

At step 4 the composed task throws the `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException`, even though the `--increment-instance-enabled` is enabled again.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException:
>   A job instance already exists and is complete for
>   parameters={-spring.cloud.data.flow.taskappname=composed-task-runner,
>   -spring.cloud.task.executionid=3190, -spring.datasource.username=testuser, -graph=aaa-stackoverflow-dummy2 && aaa-stackoverflow-dummy3, -spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default, -spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/tms_efa?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&currentSchema=dev,
>   -spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver, -spring.datasource.password=pass1234, -spring.cloud.task.name=aaa-stackoverflow, -dataflowServerUri=https://scdf-dev.company.com:443/ , -increment-instance-enabled=true}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.

Is there a better way to resume and restart the task?

Comment: Since Composed Tasks Runner is built using Spring Batch you can restart the Composed Task Run from the Jobs tab on the dashboard.

Repeat Steps 1 & 2.
But for step 3 go to the Jobs tab on the dashboard click the drop down button on the  job you want to restart.  And select `Restart the job`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Glenn. I couldn't use that function as it probably has a bug in combination with Kubernetes/Openshift. When I use the button, it will start a pod with the following arguments:
`[...]
--graph=aaa-stackoverflow-v2-dummy2 && aaa-stackoverflow-v2-dummy3
[...]
--graph=aaa-stackoverflow-v2-dummy2 && aaa-stackoverflow-v2-dummy3
--increment-instance-enabled=true
[..:]`

All of the other arguments are also passed twice.

Also I suspect that it will restart the task instead of resuming it, as it passes the `--increment-instance-enabled=true` or do I understand it wrong?